# Sequence convergence in closed Sets

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

How to proof that any sequence in $A\in R^n$ has limit also in A if A is closed?

I am interesting in proof without referering to the definition of closed set as a set where any sequences limit is also in closed set. Conversly, I am interested in opposit logic: how the fact that the set is closed guarantee that any sequence will have limit also lying in this set.

Will be very greatful for help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what you take as the definition of closed. If we take the definition below, the claim is trivial.

> A set is said to be *closed* whenever it contains all of its limit
>   points.

Let $(a_{n})_{n}$ be a sequence in $A$ converging to $a$. That is, for each neighborhood $V$ of $a$, there exists $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$, $a_{n}$ is in $V$. Can you show that $a$ is a limit point of $A$?

---

If instead we take the definition below, a bit more work is required.

> A set is said to be *closed* if it is the complement of some open set.

Let $A$ be a closed set and $(a_{n})_{n}$ a sequence in $A$ converging to some $a$. By the definition above, there exists some open set $B$ such that $A^{c}=B$. To arrive at a contradiction, suppose $a$ is in $B$. Since $B$ is a neighbourhood of $a$, it follows that the sequence $(a_n)_n$ is eventually in $B$. However, this is a contradiction, since it was assumed that the sequence $(a_{n})_{n}$ takes values in $A=B^c$.

Comment: As I sad I am interested in proof without refering to this definition of closed set. Suppose I have a set  [0,1]. I know intuitively that it is closed. But how can I proof formally that any sequence limit in this interval has limit in this interval without assuming that this interval is closed?

Comment: You have to define closed set *somehow*, otherwise the question you are asking is ill-posed. I have added a proof under the definition you might be thinking of.